# Laravel - The payload is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-6

I am using a command to execute an event to store some data to the database. But when executing the command, I get an error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException  : The payload is invalid.

When executing this event in a controller, everything works fine. The problem seems to be in the listener, when I am using `array_push`:

```
array_push($reports, $event->type);
```

`$reports` is an existing array, and I am adding one more `report_type` to that array, and then saving it to the database:

```
$event->budget->update(['reported' => $reports]);
```

Also, the `reported` field is an array field, as declared in my model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'reported' => 'array'
];
```

My question is, why does it work when executing that event from the controller, but not when using a command? And ofcourse, a fix for this would be welcome, but my main question is, that I am trying to understand the error.

If more information is needed, I will add it accordingly.

In the command I do the following:

```
foreach (reports() as $report) {
    $budgets->each(function ($budget) use ($report) {
        return event(new BudgetReported($budget, $report));
    });
}
```

My event:

```
class BudgetReported {

    use SerializesModels;

    public $budget;
    public $type;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * BudgetReport constructor.
     * @param Budget $budget
     * @param $type
     */
    public function __construct(Budget $budget, $type)
    {
        $this->budget = $budget;
        $this->type = $type;
    }
}
```

And in my listener:

```
public function handle(BudgetReported $event)
{
    $reports = $event->budget->reported;
    $reports == null ? $reports = [] : $reports;

    array_push($reports, $event->type);

    $event->budget->update(['reported' => $reports]);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Are you using decrypt helper anywhere ?

Comment: Do you use encrypted cookies or auth service during the whole process? Maybe it is due to the fact that when executing the command from CLI you don't have access to the auth service nor to the cookies.

Comment: Nope, no auth anywhere, I checked, and I am not using decrypt helper anywhere either

Comment: Paste the full code to see where the issue lies.

Comment: Alright, posted some code, hope it's enough, don't want to mess up the question with too much code

Comment: Can you show the model for BudgetReported, please?

Comment: You need to see the Budget model or the code from the event?

Comment: Most likely the Budget model.

Comment: Too much code in there but I think I know where to look now, I didn't check the model thoroughly.. I will do that first, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was with a trait I loaded in the model